# Working with Constructed (non-toplevel) Functions in Common Lisp

Tags: function, lambda, common-lisp

I'm unsure of the best way to work with functions that are not defined at the top level.

I've created a list of workhorse lambda expressions, call it `*lambdas*`, that are derived from a user's input specifications. There is also an `*args*` list that provides the appropriate arguments for each lambda. I would like to turn each lambda into a function, compile it, apply it to its respective arguments, and collect the results.

Currently, I am doing `(setf (symbol-value *dummy-fn-name*) (compile nil lambda))` as a temporary place to hold each function, followed by `(apply (symbol-value *dummy-fn-name*) args)` to get each result, but this probably qualifies as a hack. Is there a more direct way of working with the lambdas? The functions do not need to hang around after they are `apply`-ed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to put it into a global variable if it's just temporary:

```
(let ((func (compile nil lambda)))
  (apply func args))
```

or simply

```
(apply (compile nil lambda) args)
```